# cURL - Парсер с вводом капчи учитывая куки

Tags: парсер, curl, captcha

Ребята, спасайте, 3 дня разбираюсь с этой капчей, куками, сессиями , а в ответ всегда одно - wrong captcha.

Вот что я делаю не так?

Моя логика:

Человек зашел на сайт -> спарсился id типо сессии, куки -> парсится по этой сессии с этими куками капча -> человек вводит капчу -> уходит гет запрос по этим параметрам с этими же куками.

А в результат wrong captcha...

Хотя если строку GET скопировать и вставить на сам сайт https://my.maerskline.com/tracking/search , то работать будет, в чём проблема просветите , прошу вас!

index.php

```
<?php
$url = 'https://my.maerskline.com/tracking/search';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // отправляем на 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // пустые заголовки
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // возвратить то что вернул сервер
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); // следовать за редиректами
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);// таймаут4
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://fantasts.ru/forum/index.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);// просто отключаем проверку сертификата 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/my_cookies.txt'); // сохранять куки в файл
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/my_cookies.txt');
$content = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match('/captcha\?id=[0-9A-Za-z\-]{1,100}/',$content,$matches);
$captchaID= substr($matches[0],11);

$url2 ='https://my.maerskline.com/captchaapp/captcha?id='.$captchaID;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://my.maerskline.com/tracking/search");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/my_cookies.txt');
$captcha = curl_exec($ch);
file_put_contents($captchaID.'.jpg',$captcha);

include 'form.php';

if(!empty($_GET))
{
$url3 ='https://my.maerskline.com/tracking/search?randomID='.$_GET['randomID'].'&searchNumber='.$_GET['searchNumber'].'&code='.$_GET['code'];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/my_cookies.txt');
$content = curl_exec($ch);
echo $content;
curl_close($ch);
}
?>
```

form.php

```
<form action="" method="get">
<div class="header padded dark form-horizontal hidden-print">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4 trackingSearchField">
            <label><input name="searchNumber" type="text" placeholder="Shipment, B/L, Container no." value="" id="searchNumber"></label>
        <img class="pull-left captcha-img" src="<?php echo $captchaID.'.jpg'; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="randomID" name="randomID" value="<?php echo $captchaID; ?>">
                <label class="hide">Captcha</label>
                <input type="text" name="code" id="code" size="18" value="">
                <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Go">
</form>
```

Comment: Проблема решена! Если кому нужно с радостью поделюсь!

Comment: Я так понимаю, что перед отправкой формы сгенерировалась новая капча :)

Comment: нееет, проблема была лишь в том что путь к кукам был не верен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/my_cookies.txt');
```

меняем на

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__).'/my_cookies.txt');
```

Профит!